# New REST API Client option in Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, swagger, visual-studio-mac

I need to generate the swagger client SDK for my rest api in .net core project. The option "New REST API Client" is not in the context menu for the project under Add. How do I get it (or otherwise generate the SDK for my project so I can write simple tests)?

Comment: What you mean by swagger SDK?

Comment: swagger client SDK generation, sorry. edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, generate new REST API client option is not available for .NET Core projects. You can use tools like [NSwagStudio](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwagStudio) or [autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) or [Open API Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) to generate clients.

Comment: I had marked this as the answer but NSwagStudio is Windows-specific. I am having issues with autorest as well (with an enum with members like (`[EnumMember(Value = "X")] Left = 'X',`) but .. they may be resolvable. Will restore mark as answer on basis of autorest if I get that to work

Comment: Oh, I missed the mac - I have added Open API Generator as well. Please have a look.

Comment: so that is a very mature project :) Love the docker option to skip any inconsistencies. Thanks a bunch!